# Can Pygame run with 64bit Python 2.7?

Tags: python, 64-bit, pygame

I know it's advised to uninstall 64bit Python and use the win32 version to run Pygame, but I just wondered if it was possible to run it on 64bit nonetheless.

Comment: I've made it work before, but I've also seen it not work, YMMV.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have 64-bit python and it works fine for me, I suggest just using the 64bit and seeing if it works. If it doesn't work just switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, the answer is yes. I know because I had the same problem.

Once you have installed Python 2.7 on your 64-bit machine, you need to visit this web site, which is linked from the official pygame website:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

On a Windows machine, for example, you download a self installing file, which puts the pygame module in your site-package package folder within the Python directory.This directory can be found in the LIB folder.

[image]

It is really as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can try this out !

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) site has a 64bit version of PyGame on it.